# Python: Where does import come from?

Tags: python-2.7, python-import, pyro

I have had this strange problem with import in python 2.7

I have my app in a directory that has some subdirectoriers and more python apps running simultaneously using Pyro Name Server for communicating with each other.

When I run one of my apps, it crashes on import when calling one of sub methods.

Here is the exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ps_logic.py", line 15840, in <module>
    ps_logic = PSLogic(pyro_objects, cfg_handler, status_distributor, voip_processing)
  File "ps_logic.py", line 590, in __init__
    self.smarthopper_initial_check()
  File "ps_logic.py", line 12824, in smarthopper_initial_check
    counters_compared = self.smarthopper_maintenance_action()
  File "ps_logic.py", line 12928, in smarthopper_maintenance_action
    status = self.smart_hopper_logic.status_get()
  File "/home/app_core/flexcore/003-480/ps_logic/smart_devices_logic.py", line 203, in status_get
    return SmartStatusAugmented(self.smart_obj.queue_status_get(), self.smart_obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pyro/core.py", line 381, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pyro/core.py", line 456, in _invokePYRO
    return self.adapter.remoteInvocation(name, Pyro.constants.RIF_VarargsAndKeywords, vargs, kargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pyro/protocol.py", line 497, in remoteInvocation
    return self._remoteInvocation(method, flags, *args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pyro/protocol.py", line 536, in _remoteInvocation
    answer = pickle.loads(answer)
ImportError: No module named drivers.smart.smart_common_const
```

it clearly says that it cannot import `drivers.smart.smart_common_const` BUT the problem is, I do not have that line in my code.

If I try to find in which file that line is (cuz I have already fixed it in some), it finds me nothing:

```
app_core@003-481 ~/flexcore/003-480 $ grep -R "from drivers.smart.smart_common_const import" .
./drivers/.svn/pristine/23/23e13acbf9e604f179d4625e18b2b992116a98a1.svn-base:from drivers.smart.smart_common_const import *
./drivers/.svn/pristine/65/65655973d3c70a16cc982db59db8f2989366524b.svn-base:from drivers.smart.smart_common_const import *
./drivers/.svn/pristine/3b/3ba2e2518e64db9188b63247b763926544bddd90.svn-base:from drivers.smart.smart_common_const import *
app_core@003-481 ~/flexcore/003-480 $
```

but svn files.

I have been running my python app with `-v` option to find out where it is trying to import from that file. BUT it is not returning nay debug line before that exception, so I guess its something imported previously or showing nothing if import fails.

I have also deleted all `*.pyc` files and rebooted machine to be sure there is noting left in memory, but problem persisted.

Is there any other option how to find out where is the problem? I am starting to be desperate..

Answer (score 0):

That PS_Logic (whatever it may be) seems to be using Pyro to do remote calls to a server. In particular the line with the following, seems to be a remote call:

```
self.smart_obj.queue_status_get()
```

The server sends back a custom object and because it uses pickle as serialization format , your client program tries to reconstruct that object. Apparently you don't have the correct modules available in your client code, because it is *pickle* that fails when it tries to import the required module for you (to reassemble the response into objects)

There's got to be something in the manual of that ps_logic module that tells you about how to use it correctly, and that you should have it installed in the client as well perhaps.

(It is advised to not use pickle by the way, and stick to Pyro's default serializer, but that's another story)

Comment: Thank you for response. The problem however is, that `drivers.smart.smart_common_const` call is in neither client nor server part of code. Literally nowhere in any code using in those modules. Also, what does "pickle" mean? I am foreign, English is my second language and I never head that word + when using google translator, it does not give me any meaningful translation :)

Comment: This is the import used on server side: `import smart_common_const` it has no path to the file. so where does the python takes that path from?

Comment: The first question, what is "pickle": pickle is a serialization format that Python provides. It is optionally used by Pyro, the library that your ps_logic module seems to be using to talk to remote machines. The pickle protocol WILL TRY to import all required modules it needs to deserialize any content that it got from somewhere. So your server really is sending some data that contains serialized objects of a type defined in that ``smart_common_const`` library. If this is all unknown to you, you should really dive into the documentation of your software, ps_logic, and Python.

Comment: Your second question, about the import, is a basic Python question, investigate python import paths.